# Bind two Attributes["onclick"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged, rowdatabound

I got a GridView where I want to bind two events(?) when I click the first cell.

Both events/onclick are in RowDataBound.

First one gives me selectedindex so I can use SelectedIndexChanged and save row in Session.

```
     e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["onClick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvProd, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

Second one sends me to another page where Im gonna display whats saved in Session.

```
   e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["onClick"] = "location.href='products.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Namn") + "'";
```

So what I want is to fire both by one onClick. They both work single handed but that doesnt help me. I'm new and Google couldnt help me this time :(

Peace out!

Comment: Route the click to a function, which then does both tasks...

Comment: e.Row.DataItem & e.Row.RowIndex cant be reached outside RowDataBound.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you send value in url query string. A quick fix solution would be use an invisible control and set session.

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression="" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItemLeftText" ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeaderLeftTextLink" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete task" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' ImageUrl="../images/iconDelete.gif" OnClick="deleteTask" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


     protected void deleteTask(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //set session
          //Open Popup
        }
```

Now you can set session in Code behind function ( Deletetask) and call js function to open popup from codebehind

Comment: Already using invisible control to select index+save value to session. Tried to add Response.Redirect there but it didn't work.

Was hoping for a solution like the one Thorgeir posted at this moment but I guess it aint gonna be that simple.

Been sitting whole weekend with this and this whole day. So my brain is melting, time for a break.

Thanks for the tip tough!

Answer (score 0):

These are javascript commands so try adding a semicolon between the commands:

```
e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["onClick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvProd, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex) + ";location.href='products.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Namn") + "'";
```

Comment: This only runs ClientScript not the second part with ;location